# C code changes terminal text color; how can I restore defaults? Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, colors, terminal

I have a C file running on Linux. It prints some lines in red (failures) and some in green (passes). As you might expect, it uses escape codes in the *printf* statements as follows:

```
#define BLACK  "\033[22;30m"
#define GREEN  "\033[22;31m"

printf(GREEN "this will show up green" BLACK "\n");
```

If the BLACK at the end wasn't there, the terminal text will continue to be green for everything. In case you didn't catch it, that's fine for a terminal window with a non-black background, but otherwise you'll end up with black-on-black. Not good! Running the program has this problem, as does capturing the output in a text file and then viewing the file with "more" or "less".

Is there a code to restore defaults instead of specifying a color at the end of the *printf* statement?  This needs to be in C, but I would be interested in reading about other approaches.

---

I updated my macros as follows (note 31 is for red):

```
#define RESET_COLOR "\e[m"
#define MAKE_GREEN "\e[32m"

printf(MAKE_GREEN "this will show up green" RESET_COLOR "\n");
```

I found the following links helpful in understanding how these codes work:

- http://www.phwinfo.com/forum/comp-unix-shell/450861-bash-shell-escapes-not-working-via-putty-ssh.html  explains what these escape sequences do, and to use [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) if portability is needed.
- *http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-6.html*
- *[ANSI codes](http://bluesock.org/%7Ewillg/dev/ansi.html)* shows even more escape sequences; It is useful to get the big picture

Comment: The first link is (effectively) broken (the domain was not renewed). The second link is broken (times out).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using:

```
#define RESETCOLOR "\033[0m"
```

That should reset it to the defaults.

More about these terminal codes can be found in *[ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)*.

Answer (score 4):

```
"\033[0m"
```

See *[ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)*.

Answer (score 1):

Type `reset` in the terminal.

There is a binary found in Linux and OS X called *[reset](https://linux.die.net/man/1/reset)*.

Comment: Ok not the exact answer, but maybe looking at it helps.

Comment: "reset" wipes out the terminal window and places the prompt at the top of the screen, which is not the effect I need, but thank you.